# LRU cache в EJS (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, кэширование, шаблоны

Если использовать ejs без кэширования шаблонов на сервере, то порой, время отрисовки темплейта больше времени выполнения всей логики. Т.к. сначала нужно прочитать файл с диска, потом рендерить. Я начал думать о том, как бы это все закэшировать в памяти, чтоб не обращаться к диску, сначала подумал о том чтобы создать какой-нибудь класс который будет читать все ejs'ки при старте сервера в память ноды, а потом отдавать их будет уже из памяти. Но потом подумал, что может есть уже готовое решение, и правда, из коробки в ejs есть кэширование:

```
var ejs = require('ejs')
  , LRU = require('lru-cache');
ejs.cache = LRU(100);
```

Вот, если сделать так как в примере, что будет происходить? `lru-cache` - что он делает с ejs? куда он их записывает? И что означает `LRU(100)` в данном случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В точности то, о чем говорится в названии.
LRU - Least Recently Used - [Вытеснение давно неиспользуемых](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#Least_recently_used_.28.D0.92.D1.8B.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.BE_.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D1.83.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B.D1.85.29).
В вашем случае в кеше имеется 100 позиций. Когда не остаётся свободного места для новой записи, для освобождения места удаляется одна из имеющихся записей

Comment: Я так понимаю, этот кэш хранится в оперативной памяти? т.е. таким образов шаблоны не будут читаться с диска, а будут браться из памяти? (p.s. просто уточняю)

Comment: Скорее всего из памяти. Я сам этой имплементацией не пользовался, точно сказать не могу